# Why does Makoto keep her memories and is able to move when Chiaki uses his jump?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-girl-who-leapt-through-time

In The Girl Who Leapt Through Time, Makoto jumps around to avoid many of Chiaki's questions. He does not remember asking them when she leaps. However, in his final leap, she remembers everything, she remembers seeing Kousuke getting hit by the train.

**How did Makoto keep her memories?**